# why my app icon is shinking when I add badge to my menu item

Tags: android

```
private BitmapDrawable buildCounterDrawable(int count, int backgroundImageId) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menuitem_layout, null);
        view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundImageId);

        if (count == 0) {
            View counterTextPanel = view.findViewById(R.id.counterValuePanel);
            counterTextPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            textView.setText("" + count);
        }
        view.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    }
```

I used above code to add badge to menu item in my app, count is visible but icon is shinking why?

before:

[image]

image is like this:

[image]

Comment: You want to do it all by yourself? because there are some good libraries that can do the job for you.

Comment: I don't want to use libraries

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to set the bitmap drawable in the java code. I have virtually the same functionality implemented with the use of badge in an `ImageView` initially set to `invisible` in the xml and when there is notification or whatever event that is you are looking for, just set its visibility to `VISIBLE`.

Example: (implemented in a `ConstraintLayout`):

```
           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_notifications"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_notif_dot"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_notifications"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/iv_notifications"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_purple_opaque_white_outline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
```

The above XML has its root layout in `ConstraintLayout` but you can use `RelativeLayout` too in order to fix the badge icon to top or top right of your icon. To constrain to top only you can delete line: `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/iv_notifications"`

This way your java code is cleaner and you get the required UI. Let me know if you need further explanation.